# Observable<unknown>

Tags: angular

```
getCustomers():Observable<unknown>{
    return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>
    (this.baseUrl + 'customers.json')
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
getCustomer(id: number): Observable<unknown> {
    return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(this.baseUrl + 'customers.json')
      .pipe(
        map(customers => {
          let customer = customers.filter((cust: ICustomer) => cust.id === id);
          return (customer && customer.length) ? customer[0] : null;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

getOrders(id: number) : Observable<IOrder[]> {
return this.http.get<IOrder[]>(this.baseUrl + 'orders.json')
.pipe(
map(orders => {
let custOrders = orders.filter((order: IOrder) => order.customerId === id);
return custOrders;
}),
catchError(this.handleError)
);
}

I get this error:

> Type 'Observable' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable<IOrder[]>'. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type
> 'IOrder[]'.ts(2322)

How do I solve this error?

Comment: How does your handleError function look like?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what your handleError is actually doing, but error means that you expect it to return observable of IOrder[], and you don't.

Use `getOrders(id: number) : Observable<unknown> {` (look at official example https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.service.ts) or change your handleError to return correct value.

Comment: Error: src/app/customers/customer.component.ts:23:51 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?: Partial<Observer<unknown>> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(customers: ICustomer[]) => ICustomer[]' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer<unknown>>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(next: (value: unknown) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(customers: ICustomer[]) => ICustomer[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void'.
    Now this error

Answer (score 0):

The api also returns an observable so it should be like this.

```
getOrders(id: number) : Observable<IOrder[]> {
    return this.http.get<Observable<IOrder[]>>(this.baseUrl + 'orders.json')
      .pipe(
        map(orders => {
          let custOrders = orders.filter((order: IOrder) => order.customerId === id);
          return custOrders;
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: I have changed it to:

Comment: @dasari002 Is your issue resolved?